# Assistance writing the LEFT function in the INDEX MATCH EXCEL Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having an issue with the INDEX MATCH formula. This is the formula below. My problem is the cell I am trying to match is 15 characters but the target cell is 18 characters. I tried the LEFT function but it's returning `N/A`.

Can anyone please help me with my formula? I don't use excel a lot.

`=INDEX('[HOCS LIST.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$70541,MATCH(LEFT(F3,14),'[HOCS LIST.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$70541,0))`

[image]

The Target spreadsheet as you can see is 18 characters but the first 15 are exactly the same. I want my formula to look for the first 15, not the whole 18.

[image]

Thank you

I've tried the LEFT function to look for 15 characters but I still get the `N/A` result.

Comment: I would suggest to start with this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then update the question. It would help you to isolate the problem too and maybe to find a solution by your own

Comment: @Hulk Buster I can try it,if you can share the sample data.. thank you.

Comment: Should be just a wildcard search `=INDEX('[HOCS LIST.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$70541,MATCH(F3&"*",'[HOCS LIST.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$70541,0))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have the columns flipped... You don't want the first 15 characters of column F. From the screenshot that is the shorter cell, you want to compare it to column A...

```
=INDEX('[HOCS LIST.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,MATCH($F3,LEFT('[HOCS LIST.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A),0),2)
```

That being said I adjusted your index to include BOTH columns A:B along with adjusting it to return column 2 (B) assuming that's what you are looking for?